# Touching multiple web elements simultaneously brings out area with magnification for clarification of intended target – name of feature?

Tags: chrome-for-android, samsung-nexus-10, accessibility

When you touch multiple web elements simultaneously, perhaps due to the widgets being too small, and/or too close together, the area around where you touched pops out, giving you a magnified view of that area. I suppose this is so that you can clarify which interface control that you intended to touch.

Does anyone happen to know what this feature is called?

Eye tracking interfaces have a similar feature called “Gaze Clarification” for selecting small targets. As you look at your intended target, a portion of the screen that includes that target becomes magnified, and the zoom level keeps increasing and increasing as you home in on your desired spot.

[image: Android Chrome magnification for clarification]

Thanks.

Comment: I'm tempted to say "Google's Glasses", but it's rather "Magnifier". Not sure if that's the official name, though – so I don't put it as an answer ;)

Comment: Google call it "Link Preview" but in coding terms it is part of the "View Port" and you could disable it by making "User Scalable" false, here's the code for the fun of it: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's enable-link-disambiguation-popup.

> It’s a handy feature and is now available in Chrome OS.
>
> Since this is experimental, you’ll have to enable it, which is an easy process.
>
> Simply type chrome://flags in the Chrome OS browser and find the enable-link-disambiguation-popup option.
>
> Enable it and restart the browser to activate the feature.

https://gigaom.com/2014/12/23/a-key-touch-feature-from-android-is-availble-in-chrome-os/